# how to delete files using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a simple batch file that can be run on a folder where the sub-folders have files that are not dos standard, the files to be deleted are of the form *.*,1 or *.*,2 (ie log.txt,1). I want all the ,1 ,2 ,3 files to be deleted but not the original log.txt files.
What is the command structure for 'DEL' to allow this?

Comment: from reading your question I have an impression that you have file named `log.txt,1`  but in windows you can't have file named containing `,`

Comment: @npocmaka Why do you think so? `echo:>"test.txt,1"`

Comment: @LotPings - my mistake :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to quote the file name with the comma.

```
@Echo off
For /F "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S "*,*" ^| findstr ",[0-9][0-9]*$" '
) Do Echo Del "%%A"
```

- The findstr will make shure there is a trailing comma with a number.
- remove the echo in the last line if the output looks OK.